# Restrict a user so it doesn't have permission to do anything

Tags: centos, cups, non-root-user

I am trying to create a user whose only goal is to authenticate and receive jobs and files from a virtual printer (CUPS) in his home directory. The user should not be able to do anything at all. Even better if it cannot log in through SSH. Is there a way to do this other than jailing the user?

Comment: If it has no permission to do anything, then it can do nothing. That is it that you want this user to do (I see what you have said in question, but it is not clear). Please update question, to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the user with `useradd` use the option `-s`

```
-s, --shell SHELL
  The name of the user's login shell. The default is to leave this field blank, 
  which causes the system to select the default login shell specified by the SHELL variable 
  in /etc/default/useradd, or an empty string by default.
```

Give it the value `/sbin/nologin`. This will prevent the user from being able to login (if you try to login as them with username/password you will get a message saying the user is not available, this includes SSH).

`sudo -u` still works for the account (assuming you have that permission), so you can still perform tasks as them if you're root, or root allows you to.

Comment: You can su to them as root if you specify a shell also.

Comment: You should still log in to CUPS, and it uses the UNIX user and password, so this is sadly not a viable option.

Comment: @prgrm Do you mean to get the CUPS web interface? If that uses the UNIX username/password it shouldn't be an issue, only if it uses the user's shell would it be a problem

Comment: @prgrm You could also launch the CUPS GUI interface using `sudo -u`